# how to remove repetitions using map c++

Tags: c++

So i have Text.txt where are countries and rivers.So i have to output river and all countries where that current river exists.

Text.txt :

```
Spanish Taho
France Rhine
Ukrain Dnipro
Germany Rhine
Russia Dnipro
Portugal Taho
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    map<string, string> country;
    ifstream in("Text.txt");
    string key;
    string river;
    while (in >> key >> river)
    {
        country[key] = river;
    }
        map<string, string>::iterator it;
        map<string, string>::iterator it2;
        for (it = country.begin(); it != country.end(); it++) {
            cout << it->second << ":" << endl;
            for (it2 = country.begin(); it2 != country.end(); ++it2) {
                if (it->second == it2->second ) {
                    cout << "-" << it2->first << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Rhine:
-France
-Germany
Rhine:
-France
-Germany
Taho:
-Portugal
-Spanish
Dnipro:
-Russia
-Ukrain
Taho:
-Portugal
-Spanish
Dnipro:
-Russia
-Ukrain
```

What I need:

```
Rhine:
-France
-Germany
Taho:
-Portugal
-Spanish
Dnipro:
-Russia
-Ukrain
```

---

### how to remove repetitions ?

---

Some text for escape "
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is not appropriate for the solution.

Try below:

```
map<string, vector<string>> riverToCountryMap
```

And while inserting data:

> riverToCountryMap[river].push_back(country);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::multimap` for reverse order:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> m {
    {"Spanish", "Taho"},
    {"France", "Rhine"},
    {"Ukrain", "Dnipro"},
    {"Germany", "Rhine"},
    {"Russia", "Dnipro"},
    {"Portugal", "Taho"}, 
};

std::multimap<std::string, std::string> rev;

for (const auto& p : m) {
    rev.emplace(p.second, p.first);   
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6da9a90918b077be)

You might prefer `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>` over `std::multimap`.

Comment: Note that you have relation NxN, as country might have several rivers, and rivers can be in several countries, so `multimap` could be used in both side.